# For loop not evaluating

Tags: java, loops

I can't figure this out. I have the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TestLoop {
    public static List<String> strArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    static {
        strArray.add("Some");
        strArray.add("Silly");
        strArray.add("String");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int doNotPrintIndex = 1;
        int beginIndex = doNotPrintIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        for (int i = beginIndex; i < strArray.size() && i != doNotPrintIndex; i++) {
            System.out.println(strArray.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Essentially, if I have an `ArrayList`, I never want to print out what is stored at index '`doNotPrintIndex`' within the `ArrayList`. However, in the following case, the loop only executes once. Is there something wrong in my logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop is exiting as soon as `i` hits `doNotPrintIndex`. Try this loop:

```
for (int i = beginIndex; i < strArray.size(); i++) {
    if (i != doNotPrintIndex) {
         System.out.println(strArray.get(i));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could have two loops one after another:

```
for (int i = beginIndex; i < doNotPrintIndex; i++) {
     System.out.println(strArray.get(i));
}

for (int i = doNotPrintIndex + 1; i < strArray.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(strArray.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Damn it! You're right. I have spent too long thinking this through :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because `beginIndex` is 0 and `doNotPrintIndex` is 1, so after 1 iteration, i == doNotPrintIndex and the loop stops. You need to remove that from the for loop and make it an if statement inside the loop:

```
    for (int i = beginIndex; i < strArray.size(); i++) {
        if(i != doNotPrintIndex)
            System.out.println(strArray.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. For some unbeknownst reason, I was under the impression that if one of the conditions was true, the loop would just skip to the next iteration...

Answer (score 1):

The conditional in the for loop indicates when the loop should stop. You should put the test for doNotPrintIndex into the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should loop once :) You see, in a  your for loop works like this: it checks the conditions 1 and 2: `i=0, i<x && i!=1` and if this condition is true, it steps inside the for loop braces. After finishing woth operations there, it comes back and changes i: `i++`.
So when your i==1, the condition 2 is false, and the loop is over. It's like you have   `for(i=0; i<3; i++) {...}` and after last increment i equals 3. The condition i<3 is false, so the loop is finished.